# Skipping to next line of text file when delimiter reached

Tags: c++

I have a `while(inFile >> word){` loop and a text file with 10 lines:

**symbol instruction #123, $456 ;a bunch of comments**

my question is, how can I ignore anything after the semicolon and skip to next line? Essentially,

```
if(word.find(";"))
{
//move along
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different approach - first read whole line, then strip the comments after `;` and then use the rest of the line.

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    const auto commentStart = line.find(';');
    if (commentStart != std::string::npos)
    {
        line.erase(commentStart); //strip comments
    }
    ... //use the line somehow
}
```

If you want to have separate words after line was read, you can use e.g. [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) (but there are [many different options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string)):

```
std::stringstream ss(line);
std::string word;
while(ss >> word) {
    //use single word
}
```

Comment: Extremely helpful! Thank you